# Getting Webdriver ElementNotVisibleException when I try to click on a hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, selenium, click, webdriver

I am trying to click on a link using webdriver but it throws me a ElementNotVisibleException saying "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

My WebDriver code:

```
addProgram.click();
```

addProgram refers to an anchor element. This is populated by annotating @FindBy(how= How.LINK_TEXT, using="Add Program"). In other words it is similar to driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Program")).

My HTML is:

```
<div class="form_btn">
<a href="/program/addProgram">   
<span>Addrogram</span
</a>
</div>
```

It starts working when I remove the css declaration from the above div. The dive has a hover style, may be that is the one causing the problem.

CSS:

```
.form_btn { 
    float:left; 
background:url(/bg_button_right.gif) no-repeat scroll top     
    right; 
color: #fff; 
display: block; 
height:22px; 
font: bold 10px arial; 
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-top:2px; 
padding-right: 4px; /* sliding doors padding */ 
text-decoration: none; 
}

.form_btn span { 
background:url(/assets/images/provider/bg_button_left.gif) no-repeat; 
display: block; 
float:left; 
line-height:18px; 
padding: 2px 5px 5px 10px; 
font-size:11px; 
}

.form_btn a{ 
color:#fff;
}

.form_btn a:hover{ 
color:#fff; 
text-decoration:none; 
cursor:hand;
}
```

I have trawled the web trying to find a solution but none has worked. Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(UPDATE) This issue was resolved and should be available since Selenium 2.4.0

Sounds like you ran into the same bug as I did:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1445

the work-around is to get the element inside the link and click.

re-writing your code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Program")).findElementBy(By.tagName("span"))
```

Comment: I actually solved it yesterday, I was postponing updating this thread. I clicked on the container div and it worked. Similar to your solution but opposite :) in that you clicked on the inner element of the hyperlink, I clicked on the outer element(container )of the hyperlink.

Comment: But the bug link that you have posted here doesn't happen for me. In my case the problem is due to the CSS, the moment I remove the css declaration on the div it starts working. I think there is some link between the hover and the visibility of the div/href.

Comment: Your case is exactly the bug :) The CSS that you are removing that causes it to work is "float:left" on the nested span element ~ which is causing the link to have an effective height of 0px. WebDriver doesn't allow you to click on links that "aren't displayed" ~ display:none, visibility:hidden, height:0, width:0 (and in 2.0b3, but not future releases opacity:0)

Comment: Funny how a float:left on the span will make the href to have a height of 0. Since I see the div, which is the container for the href, has a height of 22px in the css. I am not well versed in CSS but I would like to understand what you are trying to convey. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the rules around this are, but I do know it's all about how block and inline elements interact with floats... adding display:inline-block to the .form_btn a{} would also fix this, but that won't work in IE6-7

Answer (score 1):

I just solve this error while using capybara in ror project by add  " Capybara.ignore_elements = true " to features/support/env.rb

Answer (score 0):

Working from @Zernel's solution, the following solves for ror project using capybara.

Add `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true` to the file `config/environments/test.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Using texts is not always the good methodology.

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form_btn > a[href*='addProgram'] > span")).click();
```

Always Use CSS, It performs better than XPath.